# Sort a View SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am trying to find a way to sort the results in a view. I know the `Order by` command does not work. The reason for this is that we are using a BI tool 'Board' to drill through to the raw data. Unfortunately there is no way in the program to sort a drill through as I would a regular query since the `Where` clause is dynamic and the program always puts it at the end of the query.

Hence an `Order by` would appear prior to a `Where` which results in an error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple of ways to achieve this, one is to make sure that the data the view is reading is already sorted, to do this, you make sure that the indexes on the table/s that the view is reading from are sorted the way you want, if this isn't possible, then you could also create a clustered index on the view itself and specify the sort order there.

If creating indexes is not possible, there is another way that I have found to work, but is not always ideal as it creates an extra column in your result set that doesn't mean anything, you can do this:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [col1] ASC ) AS [sort_col] ,
        [col1] ,
        [col2] ,
        [col3]
FROM    [dbo].[table];
```

If you do this, you will end up with the extra column giving the row number, but the data will be sorted by [col1].  One thing to mention with this is that if you do put this into the view definition, you must still select that column in your query for the sorting to take place.